# How to avoid ban when uses scrapy

Tags: scrapy, python-3.5

I'm getting constantly ban from a website, I set download_delay = 10 in scrapy, I tried a package [fake_user_agent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent) then I tried implementing tor and polipo, according to this [site](https://check.torproject.org/) the config is ok. But after running 1/2 times again I got banned! Can anyone help me here ?

Note: [scrapy-proxie](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) I also want to try this but can't activate.

Comment: You need to provide more information, such as what site you're crawling, what you're doing when crawling, etc.  If the site is banning you, you're likely doing something it doesn't like, or that it finds violates it's ToS.  Without more information, no one here could tell you why you're being banned.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is to talk to the site owners and ask them. If you're violating their ToS they are well within their rights to limit your access. Nothing we can do about that, and in my opinion, nothing we *should* help you circumvent either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the likely reason is a violation of the ToS of the website and the OP should talk to the site owners first to figure out if there is a correct way to grab data from their site.

Comment: Actually I am trying to scrape from rarbg.to, just for learning purpose! Just want to extract some data like movie title, size, quality etc so that I can built a app which notify me when any new movie arrieved which imdb rating is greater than 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at what the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=avoid%20getting%20banned#avoiding-getting-banned) says.

> Here are some tips to keep in mind when dealing with these kinds of
> sites:
>
> - rotate your user agent from a pool of well-known ones from browsers
>   (google around to get a list of them)
> - disable cookies (see
>   COOKIES_ENABLED) as some sites may use cookies to spot bot behaviour
> - use download delays (2 or higher). See DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting.
> - if
>   possible, use Google cache to fetch pages, instead of hitting the
>   sites directly use a pool of rotating IPs. For example, the free Tor
>   project or paid services like ProxyMesh
> - use a highly distributed
>   downloader that circumvents bans internally, so you can just focus on
>   parsing clean pages. One example of such downloaders is Crawlera

Comment: Really thanks!  Can u give me any tutorial or example projects about Rotating IP, I really stuck here!

Comment: [This](http://pkmishra.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/how-to-run-scrapy-with-TOR-and-multiple-browser-agents-part-1-mac/) one seems pretty good. If it helped you, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use delay on clicks
2. Not tor - all connections from one address - bad, rotate proxy after several visits

And check this post - [web scraping etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022030/web-scraping-etiquette)